# how to overlay an element over an html5 video in css in firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox

Basically I have an HTML 5 video which I need to overlay a div over it wither the video is fullscreen or !fullscreen.

All around the web I found was `z-index:2147483647;` as best recommendation.
This worked with chrome and opera but in firefox if the video goes to fullscreen then my `div (video controls container)` disappears and does not overlay over the video.

CSS:

```
.MyVideo{
    position:relative; // I also Tried Absolute and without any position;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:black;
    z-index:1;
}

.overlay_over_video{
    position:absolute;
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    background:white;
    z-index:2147483647;
}
```

All replies are appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure, so I can't post as an answer, but do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/53zzpaja/ there's a video behind the white

Comment: @toast Yes that's what I meant but in video fullscreen mode.